# Save in a variable 1 record of query -datastore

Tags: nosql, dialogflow-es, datastore

How I put one data of a query in a variable?????? in datastore
I created a query filter by 'casa' and now I want select the first data of this query and put in a variable.

```
const query1 = datastore.createQuery('tabla1').filter('Campo1', '=', ''casa');
    var  dato1 = '';  
     datastore.runQuery(query1).then((results) => {
          dato1 = results[0][0].CampoName; 
      });
    conv.ask(dato1);
```